# Changes pages in WinForms (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

So, I'm new to Visual Studio and I'm trying to make a simple multi-page WinForms program in Visual C#. How do I change the "page" that the program is displaying like a normal program does? So far the best I can do is close/hide one Form and open another in its place.

Comment: Are you referring to MDI child forms? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7aw8zc76(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

WinForms doesn't have a notion of "pages". That mechanism was made popular later on the windows client, with WPF. One could argue that WinForms apps are more *normal* than the rest. ;)

One thing you could do to simulate it, would be to make your "pages" in UserControls, and then add/remove them from the form dynamically.